# How to convert Java library to Webassembly

Tags: java, maven, webassembly, teavm

I am relatively new to TeaVM and overall converting to webassembly. I have created Java 11 library which is meant to be used for calculations - so far it has one Core module which consist of logic used for calculations. I want to convert this java library to webassembly (.wasm file) so it can be used on frontend (React app).

I have found [TeaVM](https://teavm.org/) that can compile my java code to this format. I followed these steps:

1. Add TeaVM dependency and configuration to my Maven *pom.xml*
2. Annotated function with *@Export(name="nameOfFunction")*
3. Run *mvn clean package*

Next, I wanted to make sure that function has been added so I opened generated .wasm file [here](https://webassembly.github.io/wabt/demo/wasm2wat/) and tried to look for function name but did not succeeded so I guess it has not been added then.

Are there any additional steps required in order to achive .wasm file generated using TeaVM please? Thanks for any help

This is part of my pom.xml related to TeaVM:

```
// rest of pom.xml

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.teavm</groupId>
            <artifactId>teavm-classlib</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.teavm</groupId>
                <artifactId>teavm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <targetDirectory>${project.build.directory}/webapp/wasm</targetDirectory>
                            <targetFileName>complexlogic.wasm</targetFileName>
                            <targetType>WEBASSEMBLY</targetType>
                            <optimizationLevel>FULL</optimizationLevel>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is function I am trying to export (it is just an example so it is just easy calculation):

```
import org.teavm.interop.Export;

// rest of code

    @Export(name = "getMagicNumber")
    public int getMagicNumber(int range) {
        return range * 2;
    }

// rest of code
```

Comment: Have you tried just using that generated WASM?

Comment: Yes, but I was unable to use it in my react app but that is different issue. First, I want to be sure that annotated functions were “translated” to webassembly.

Comment: Have you tried a simple HTML/JavaScript just for testing this? Seems that TealVM can generate that for you.

Comment: I tried to create a React app with fetching my .wasm file and then printing into console but I only get some errors regarding to **instantiateStreaming** method. This is the site I used for this whole task: [link](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/java-in-the-browser-webassembly-tutorial-wasm-teavm-html-javascript). Can you give me more info where I can find how to generate this HTML/JS please? I tried to read the documentation but it is kind of poor.